# fancybox width auto resize after second click on image

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I've recently updated fancybox to 1.3.4 and since then my fancybox window doesn't resize horizontal correctly. 
When I first click on a link to fire the fancybox, the window has too small width size and cut the image. When I close fancybox and open it again the window resize fine and image is fully visible.
After page reload it starts again the same.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: in previous fancybox version I was using 1.3.0, everything was working fine.

Comment: with - autoScale : true, autoDimensions : true

Comment: can you paste the whole .fancybox() statement ?

Comment: Im calling fancybox without any parameters. All is set in fancybox plugin with default settings. I just changed autoScale : true, autoDimensions : true

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
enter code here
afterLoad  : function () {  
        $(".fancybox-title").wrapInner('<div />').show();   
        var lebarLayar = $(window).width();
        var tinggiLayar = $(window).height();
        var imgWidth = this.width;
        var imgHeight = this.height;
        if (lebarLayar > tinggiLayar) {
            //alert($(window).height() + " : " + $(window).innerHeight());
            frameHeight = tinggiLayar;
            frameWidth = tinggiLayar/imgHeight * imgWidth;
        }
        else if (lebarLayar < tinggiLayar) {
            //alert($(window).height() + " : " + $(window).innerHeight());
            frameWidth = lebarLayar;
            frameHeight = lebarLayar/imgWidth * imgHeight;
        }
        $.extend(this, {
            width   : frameWidth,
            height  : frameHeight,
        });
    },



enter code here
```

hope help you